# How do I allow `javascript:void(0)` for use in HTML element attributes through Content-Security-Policy?

Tags: javascript, http, content-security-policy

I want to be able to do

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)">
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
```

to make sure nothing happens even if the handler fails to prevent the default action. How should I declare this to be allowed using the `Content-Security-Policy` HTTP response header without resorting to `unsafe-eval`?

Comment: Why not use `href="#"`?

Comment: Because it would jump to the page's top if not prevented.

Comment: It's probably better to make sure any branch of your handler prevents the action rather than putting that action/href there.

Comment: `href="#_"` or something like this won't jump

Comment: You don't actually need the href attribute ... see my answer

Comment: @Ilya Streltsyn suggested href="#_", but I have found this to not be true. the action in my tests is just the same as href="#"

Answer (score 5):

I've recently applied CSP policy to a huge VUE project, by adding meta headers to index.html.

Google Chrome would print a warning about `javascript:` links, but nothing else happens apart from that.

What I did is simply remove the `href="javascript:` attribute, and added a style to maintain the cursor style:

```
a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And it worked great for me.

P.S I also replaced several `<a>` with `<button>` tag, and `<button>` does not require a href attribute.

Comment: This works perfectly fine in every instance in my experiencce.

Answer (score 4):

I believe in your question you contradict yourself.

> How do I allow `javascript:void(0)` for use in HTML element attributes
>   through Content-Security-Policy?

On one hand, you set a [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) header to which you specify a rule which I'm guessing is `script-src`. A directive used to prevent inline scripts from running.

On the other hand, you want to bypass it and execute inline javascript.

Isn't the header working just as expected?

Adding `'unsafe-inline'` will bypass it, but negates the idea of disallowing inline styles and inline scripts (one of the biggest security wins CSP provides).

You can use a nonce-source to only allow specific inline script blocks.

Example:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'nonce-2726c7f26c'
```

Note, you will have to set the same nonce on the  element as well.

```
<script nonce="2726c7f26c">
  var inline = 1;
</script>
```

For your case using forms, the header would be:

```
Content-Security-Policy: form-action 'nonce-<value>'
```

Alternatively, you can create hashes from your inline scripts. CSP supports sha256, sha384 and sha512.

Example:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'sha256-076c8f1ca6979ef156b510a121b69b6265011597557ca2971db5ad5a2743545f'
```

Note, that when generating the hash, don't include the  tags and note that capitalization and whitespace matter, including leading or trailing whitespace.

```
<script>var inline = 1;</script>
```

Comment: Using Content-Security-Policy I can specify what is allowed and what is not. I would like to allow this specific instance of javascript url to be allowed without allowing all javascript urls, to decrease the attack surface of hackers.

Comment: So basically I have `script-source 'self'` and would like to change it to allow this single javascript url as well..

Comment: @JonasBerlin The only solution I am aware of in order to bypass this restriction using CSP is to use 'unsafe-inline'. But I believe it negates the whole CSP idea.

Comment: @JonasBerlin I've updated my answer with a couple of things you could try.

Comment: Does the `nonce` work also with <form action="..."> and similar?

Comment: @JonasBerlin You should be able to use: Content-Security-Policy: form-action 'nonce-<value>'

Comment: I don’t think there’s any way to use `nonce-` or `sha256-` with a `javascript:` URL in a `<form>` `action` (and it must be in a `<form>` `action`, because the default `action` causes a page navigation, which the OP is trying to guarantee won’t happen).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into (and reported) this [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1468274) when trying to do exactly that.  I wanted to guarantee that data in my `<form>` wouldn’t traverse the network even if some freak JavaScript error prevents the `submit` event from being cancelled.  But Firefox will incorrectly trigger a CSP error based on the `action` of a submitted `<form>` *even when the `submit` event is cancelled* by `return false` or `event.preventDefault()`.

The workaround I came up with is to use an **invalid `blob:` URL**!

```
<form action="blob:">
```

Attempts to submit a `<form>` to `blob:` seem to be silently ignored.  There’s no navigation, nothing sent over the network, and no CSP error, whether the `submit` event is cancelled or not.  (You probably still want to make every effort to cancel it, of course.)

It seems to work for links too, although Chrome shows an error in the console here:

```
<a href="blob:">
```

If you come up with something less horrendous, please share!

Answer (score 1):

What about removing the built-in event and replacing it with an AJAX call?

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_examples.asp

Comment: OP implies he's already doing that. He also has that action/href as a failsafe to prevent the action anyway in case the handler fails. The question here is regarding the `Content-Security-Policy` and how OP can use it to say that "it's ok to use `javascript:void(0)` as an action/href here"

Answer (score 0):

As  `<a href="javascript:void(0);">` violates the **Content Security Policy** the best thing you can do is not use it and change it by:

```
 <a href="#" onClick="return false;">
```

These do the same work without problem.

Comment: Works for links ([more or less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360297/how-do-i-allow-javascriptvoid0-for-use-in-html-element-attributes-through-c/54546164#comment79680489_46360297)), but unfortunately submitting `<form action="#">` still causes a page load in Chrome.

Comment: So you're removing a javascript function and adding one? I don't get it.

Comment: Since you wrote `onClick` and not `onclick`, I assume you‘re using React unlike the OP. React uses synthetic events, and turns `onClick` into a global event handler on the react root, which uses a function reference for handling, therefore works fine with CSP. This does not apply for non-react `onclick` handlers.